# NSDictionary Key exists but returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a dictionary which does contain an object but is returns nil.

```
// returns nil
(lldb) po [_contentRatings objectForKey:rating]
nil
// this is the rating string
(lldb) po rating
'=7+’
// using a literal string works
(lldb) po [_contentRatings objectForKey:@"'=7+'"]
5
```

It must be not liking the quotes since this fails string equality:

```
(lldb) po @"'=7+'"
'=7+'
(lldb) po rating
'=7+’
(lldb) p (BOOL)[@"'=7+'" isEqualToString:rating]
(BOOL) $10 = NO
```

Comment: Have you tried NSLog-ing your dictionary? It will log all objects and keys. Would give you a better idea if the object is in there or not.

Comment: It is there i just copied this from the debugger: [11] (null) @"'=7+'" : (int)5

Comment: Look at the last quote character for the value of `rating`. It is not the simple quote character you are using in your literal.

Comment: Thank you! it was so hard to see in the debugger with my font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'` ([unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm): apostrophe) mark is different from `’` ([unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm): right single quotation mark)
hence `'=7+'` isn't equal to `'=7+’` (mind the last character)

Comment: Thanks, i couldn't see it with the font i was using in xcode.